# What to do when user input exceeds the desired bound using fgets?

Tags: c

I wanted to know how to deal with a situation when I set the size of buffer in fgets to n bytes and the user enters 2n bytes? fgets will reaf the first n bytes, and the other n bytes will be left in stdin, right? Is it a good idea to flush stdin after each fgets, is there any other optiob to deal with that situation?

Comment: don't flush stdin, it's undefined behaviour. Rather, use a fgetc() loop until EOF.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre EOL presumably...

Comment: It depends on what you want to do? discard rest of the line? resize your input buffer?

Comment: In this situation, I usually grow the input buffer (e.g., double the size using realloc) and continue to read. And yes, the remaining bytes remain there in stdin and can be read by subsequent fgets calls.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala probably. Too lazy to look that up. Congrats for the c gold badge BTW. Maybe you could find a good dupe of that one and close it :)

Comment: Note the options discussed in [Why the `gets()` function is so dangerous it should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309845/15168).  My normal technique is to set the size large (4096 bytes, typically) and then largely ignore the problem — [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).  But I do mean that size of buffer.  OTOH, you might be parsing JSON-style data that could all be on one line and might be larger.  In that case, `getline()` is good, or you can use `fgets()` in a loop resizing the array as you go (but `getline()` does that automatically).

Comment: A good answer needs to address the higher level goals of the program - which are not stated.  Append the goals of the program to get good applicable ideas -else this is too broad.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it's fine to flush `stdin`. Just not with the `fflush` function

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answers everyone, I want to clarify what I mean. For instance I want to user to enter a name and give him 20 bytes for it, but he decides to enter 30, I don't want the extra 10 bytes, so I can either flush it or I can provide a bigger container. In a case of the providing bigger container size the user can always enter an input longer than the container size, so if I provide 4096 bytes, he can enter 5000 and so on. So, I guess my question is how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

You know when the input was truncated by the absence of a `'\n'` newline at the end of the input string.

Except possibly for the last line in a text file, which might not contain any newline.

If there is more input, you can `realloc` the buffer (originally acquired with `malloc`) and repeat with the appropriate buffer pointer (and size) to append to what you already have.

No need to flush anything, just pass the right pointer and additional buffer size to `fgets`.

In any case, flushing input with `fflush()` is not well defined.

Comment: good point. Maybe add the way of flushing input for the remaining chars for an upvote?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre am tempted to provide a code example, but OP did not provide any.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre re OP's question *Is it a good idea to flush stdin after each `fgets`* - No there is no reason to flush input you actually want.